# In excel, is there a way to insert commas into numbers which themselves are embedded in normal-text?

Tags: excel, csv, formatting

Suppose in Excel  If have a column like so:

```
STGADM.CK_ACCT - 6863349
STGADM.CK_ADJ - 10378906
STGADM.CK_BILL - 81880214
STGADM.CK_BSEG - 80849690
STGADM.CK_FT - 162025408
STGADM.CK_MR - 124169555
STGADM.CK_MTR - 6953099
STGADM.CK_MTR_CONFIG - 6953099
STGADM.CK_PAY - 77355566
STGADM.CK_PAY_EVENT - 77355566
STGADM.CK_PAY_SEG  - 70599993
STGADM.CK_PER - 12815378
STGADM.CK_PREM - 3615420
STGADM.CK_REG - 11073352
STGADM.CK_SA - 7278306 
STGADM.CK_SA_REL - 7277478 
STGADM.CK_SA_SP - 6867294
STGADM.CK_SP - 3619179
STGADM.CK_SP_MTR_HIST - 7676930
```

And I want to insert commas into the numbers on the right. I can't do that [through normal way](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelformatting/ss/number_format_2.htm) , because the cell has  *both* characters and numbers. How can I do  this ? Or shall I use generic regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With values in column **A** , in **B1** enter:

```
=MID(A1,1,FIND(" - ",A1)+3) & TEXT(--MID(A1,FIND(" - ",A1)+3,9999),"#,##0")
```

and copy down.  **B1** should show:

STGADM.CK_ACCT - 66,863,349